# PHP verify .doc/.docx document respects template

Tags: library, php, web-apis, microsoft-word

I am now writing a PHP web application which manages theses and I only have one problem left: I have to verify if the submitted document respects a given format/template (e.g. LNCS). Could you suggest some library/api/web service or anything that could help me with this?

Comment: Do you need *both* doc and docx support?

Comment: It's preferable, but i can settle for only one of them if necessary

Comment: What do you mean by LNCS? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lecture_Notes_in_Computer_Science ?

Comment: Are you OK with taking a few days to tailor a script to recognize the "template" elements you need? Or do you want a tool that parses a "template model file" automatically?

Comment: I would prefer a tool. I simply need to verify if the font is correct, it has the right indentation, and is structured correctly, etc. ...that is, if such a tool exists.

Comment: I don't know of any such tool but I would think that [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord) would be a pretty good starting point. (I haven't used it yet so I can't give a good recommendation)